# nftables rules syantax getting error in adding rule

Tags: linux, nftables, netfilter

I am trying to add this rule

```
nft insert rule ip nat PREROUTING iifname enp0s3 udp dport 9100 counter dnat to 192.168.150.2
```

I am getting this error

```
[root@ph3ro]# nft insert rule ip nat PREROUTING iifname enp0s3 udp dport 9100 counter dnat to 192.168.150.2
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
insert rule ip nat PREROUTING iifname enp0s3 udp dport 9100 counter dnat to 192.168.150.2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[root@ph3ro]#
```

Can someone please help me in this case

Comment: [Please do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702201/108618).

Comment: Now the question is available on only one site... you'll have to start by telling what is already in place. Because this command alone can't work. Please provide the output of: `nft list ruleset` in the question.